# Property Y does not exist on type 'FunctionComponent<Interface>' even though Interface contains property Y

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-typescript

I have 3 components, Grid, BlockWrapper, and Block.

Block is a children of BlockWrapper.

Block has the props blockClassName and text, which I specified in an interface:

Grid/index.tsx

```
    const blockWrappers:Array<JSX.Element> = [];
    const blocks:Array<JSX.Element> = [];
    
    // ...

    for(let i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
        blocks.push(
            <Block
                blockClassName={ blockClassName }
                text={i + ""}
            />
        );
        
        blockWrappers.push(
            <BlockWrapper index={i} >
                { blocks[i] }
            </BlockWrapper>
        )
    }

    // ...


    interface BlockProps {
        blockClassName: string,
        text: string
    }
    
    swappable.on("swappable:swapped", () => {
        for(let wrapper of blockWrappers) { // blockWrappers is an array of BlockWrapper
            let child = wrapper.props.children as React.FunctionComponent<BlockProps>; // Getting child of BlockWrapper, which is Block
            if(child.blockClassName) console.log(); // Error: Property 'blockClassName' does not exist on type 'FunctionComponent<BlockProps>'.ts(2339)
        }
        updateClasses();
    });
```

Block/index.tsx

```
const Block = ( {blockClassName, text}: {blockClassName: string, text: string} ) => {
    if(blockClassName.includes("isEmpty")) text = "";
    return (
        <span className={blockClassName}>
            <Content>
                <h1>{text}</h1>
            </Content>
        </span>
    );
}
```

However, when I try to access blockClassName from child, which is a FunctionComponent, it gives me an error saying the property "blockClassName" does not exist in child. I already specified in BlockProps that it has a property called "blockClassName," and I don't see why the error is showing up. How can I fix this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In what you've shown, `blockWrappers` is an array of `React.ReactElement`, each with a single child. That's not `React.FunctionComponent<BlockProps>`, which is a function type, it's `React.ReactElement<BlockProps>`.

You can access that single child via [`React.Children.only`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactchildrenonly) (if there were more, you'd use one of the other methods on `React.Children`)):

```typescript
const child = React.Children.only<React.ReactElement<BlockProps>>(wrapper.props.children);
```

and then just as with the wrapper, you need to use `.props` to see the child's props:

```typescript
console.log("blockClassName = ", child.props.blockClassName);
```

E.g.:

```typescript
for (const wrapper of blockWrappers) {
    const child = React.Children.only<React.ReactElement<BlockProps>>(wrapper.props.children);
    if (child.props.blockClassName) {
        console.log("blockClassName = ", child.props.blockClassName);
    }
}
```

[Playground link showing the types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgIilQ3wG4Aoc4AOxiSk3STgCEAbCNAawAUcwAznADe5OOLgAjDtwDCbFAIEA5FCCQAuOAJhQaAcwA0YiXQAeMLTr3V95AL6U0EajriyXdWluToYAOgAxWTgAXjgACmE0AAtgNgATImp7AEowgD44AB4E4AA3DOi4xOT7bIB6PMKKcmdXeHZOLjDIkWlm+UUVNSRDOHMYey0m7j4IQTh00KzRCThgTEiOuQUlVXV-GjQ2AFcEpAEI-GABAFFwGABPfFT0wdb8MhNxIhhdqGpIl-mcgTAUF8dt0NkhQsIVlwuutevYMj9fhJsh5aEhaPDEZikTEAIxFQblCq4jFYpEVFFeGAkxGVf6A6lTCj2Wr1NyjLgAdSgKDAYHoPmIAWCrSisXiSTRaUyOWqRTFpUllVlLJcbkhXJ5fKgQnCAG0ftl2RrefQMoaZC1IdCeupQvgUPgBkgLHaHg64BUzRUjdyTVAMsZ5ubmsatWb2VILdbQXbJI7Bq7nfA4x6vT7NabA0j037wxbI501jawfg0PGk4mLHAy6nKjmw8YALq1TDQSKs+AAd19WrgECW6p79AE6TmEg71ZKCVavgw-lkU+S-hcbCu2VnAQ3ZzYSHUtGDY34AgyGQi3YzUH8YCP-nlEuoqQo80W7anV5vVqLoNHCPHqogO7+Bw+jHJ+IK9I8-R3u+EwCP4YEwuoj4-I4jhAA) *(a simplified version I created before your edit)*